# Pig Script Matching Tuple Entries by Position

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a file with two columns, each a comma separated list:
a,b,c   0.27,0.32,0.02

I want to split this into multiple rows in such a way that each entry in the first column is matched up with the corresponding entry in the second column. They will both always have the same number of entries. The output I am trying to get is:

```
a   0.27
b   0.32
c   0.02
```

I tried tokeinizing and flattening both columns, but that gives me 9 rows

```
a   0.27
a   0.32
a   0.02
b   0.27
b   0.32
b   0.02
c   0.27
c   0.32
c   0.02
```

This is NOT what I want. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the below code:
A = load 'inp' using PigStorage() as (firstcol:chararray, secondcol:chararray);

first_part = foreach A generate flatten(col2row(firstcol)) as (count:int, value:chararray);
second_part = foreach A generate flatten(col2row(secondcol)) as (count:int, value:chararray);

joined = join first_part by count, second_part by count;
output = foreach joined generate first_part::value as col1, second_part::value as col2;

dump output;

and the UDF col2row is:
public class col2row1 extends EvalFunc{

```
TupleFactory mTupleFactory = TupleFactory.getInstance();
BagFactory mBagFactory = BagFactory.getInstance();


public DataBag exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String inp = (String) input.get(0);
    int count = 0;
    DataBag out = mBagFactory.newDefaultBag();

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(inp,",");
    while(st.hasMoreElements())
    {       
        count++;

        Tuple t1 = mTupleFactory.newTuple();
        t1.append(count);
        t1.append(st.nextElement());
        out.add(t1);
    }
    return out;
}
```

If you want to use built in TOKENIZE in Pig then you can do make a slight change in the UDF. Then the UDF should take a Bag as input instead of string. Basically what i tried to do is to modify two parts of input - a,b,c & 0.27,0.32,0.02 as :
 (1,a) (2,b) (3,c) &
 (1,0.27) (2,0.32) (3,0.02).

and then I performed join based on first variable giving the desired output

Comment: I am getting an error when using col2row UDF: `grunt> c1t = FOREACH c1 GENERATE myudfs.col2row(qs);
2014-08-04 12:43:55,838 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: could not instantiate 'myudfs.col2row' with arguments 'null'` I am not sure what the issue is. I tried a different UDF and that works fine.

Comment: Fixed it. EvalFunc in the extends clause should be: EvalFunc<DataBag>. Works now. Thanks for your help.